# How to specify Logout Service in the PingFederateSLOURL in mod_pf configuration

Tags: pingfederate

We are using PingFederate as Service Provider and are using Opentokenadapter.
We are also using mod_pf apache library provided by PingFederate.

Is there any way we can configure "**Logout Service (present in OpenToken Adapter  )**" in the mod_pf configuration? Is there any query parameter for it just like we have for PartnerIdpId, TargetResource etc?

Answer (score 0):

The Apache Integration Kit's mod_pf.conf refers to the /sp/startSLO.ping application endpoint. In that configuration file is where you will configure various bits for the integration... You can review the /sp/startSLO.ping options as listed here:
https://documentation.pingidentity.com/pingfederate/pf81/index.shtml#concept_spServices.html#concept_spServices

The "Logout Service", as defined in the adapter, is where the browser will be sent to for an SLO that will destroy any current session within the SP Application. By spec, that application *must* return BACK to PingFederate, so that PingFederate can respond back to the IdP with a success/fail. If you plan to support SLO, then this "service" *must* exist. It's "goal" will be close the session, and redirect back to PingFederate with a success.

Comment: We are using PF version 7.2.1.2 and have configured SP initiated SLO by defining PingFederateCancelURL and PingFederateSLOURL url. If we don't define "Logout Service" in Opentoken Adapter, /sp/startSLO.ping call throws 500 Internal error with below error:
**org.sourceid.websso.profiles.ProcessRuntimeException: org.sourceid.saml20.adapter.AuthnAdapterException: Logout functionality invoked, but no logout service is configured for this adapter.**

Comment: Could you please confirm if "Logout Service" is mandatory in case of SP initiated SLO? If not could you please guide as to what could be wrong in the configuration?

Comment: Yes, it's required for both IdP-init and SP-init SLO, and I've modified the answer.

Comment: So if I have multiple applications authenticating to same IDP, then I will have to create multiple adapters by setting respective application logout url in "Logout Service" url or is there any way where I can reuse the adapter by mentioning "Logout Service" in the configuration somewhere? Can logout service have some variable which can help in determining the application from which the "Logout Service" was called?

Comment: No. You need a service per adapter. The simplest thing is something within the same domain that deletes your session cookie (because, frankly, you should probably only have ONE session cookie for identity in your org - if that's not the case, then you probably should go back to the architecture drawing board).